# is there a way to check the memory used, memory free and even memory leaks in Android/Xamarin/c#/net

Tags: c#, android, memory, memory-leaks, xamarin

Checking the topics and the posts in the forum I see there is a fair amount of error and exceptions related to memory leaks and memory usage. Is there a way to check the memory leaks with android... With some tool in Xamarin to do it or programatically via Console?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Xamarin Profiler](http://xamarin.com/profiler) was just announced at [Evolve](http://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-platform-previews/) this week.